# How i can avoid getting content from outside the loop?

Tags: java

If I write:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("please select a weapon to kill this long range zombie: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Choose: ");
        System.out.printf("1:Knife  %n2:Shutgun %n3:Sniper" );
        
                
        while(true) {
        
        Scanner myWeapons = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println(" ");
        

        int userChoice = myWeapons.nextInt();
        
      
            
        if( userChoice != 3 )  {
            System.out.println("you selected the wrong weapon,please select a long range weapon");
            
            
        } else {
            
            System.out.println("great you selected the sniper");
            
            break;
            
        }   
            System.out.println("let's play another game");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Each time I take a response I will also get "let's play another game" printed. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEjkP.png

Comment: What do you mean "content from outside the loop"? Your "let's play another game" is *inside* the loop. Though your indentation is messed up; perhaps that is misleading you.

Comment: What do you mean "content from outside the loop"? Your "let's play another game" is inside the loop - i was thinking that by "break;" i will make the loop stop especially since i closed the else with the "}" , it was just my bad placement as the Answer said,thanks for your question,i appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to wait for the user to enter a long range weapon then it means you need to loop infinitely until user input weapon is not 3. You were thinking in right direction but the code block placement wasn't right. Try this code which wait indefinitely until `userChoice` is not 3.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("please select a weapon to kill this long range zombie: ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Choose: ");
    System.out.printf("1:Knife  %n2:Shutgun %n3:Sniper" );
            
    Scanner myWeapons = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
    System.out.println(" ");

    int userChoice = myWeapons.nextInt();
    while(userChoice != 3)  {
        System.out.println("you selected the wrong weapon,please select a long range weapon");
        userChoice = myWeapons.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("great you selected the sniper");
    
    System.out.println("let's play another game");
    
}
```